# Memory issues with UIImage Animation Image Caching

Tags: swift, animation, keyboard, uiimage, uicollectionview

I've been banging my head against this for days now and just can't get to the bottom of it. Basically i have the keyboard extension which uses a UICollectionView to display animated UIImages. When it's running and i switch to another app then switch back to the keyboard i'm getting a spike around 10mb. This obviously crashes the app after a few swaps.

I've gone through instruments and it looks like I'm getting heaps of extra UIImages when the keyboard reloads, they 'eventually' get cleaned up but it takes a while and the accumulative effect max's out the memory. I think it's to do with the UIImage caching the animation image as i start with around 150 - 200 UIImages, which roughly correlates to the total animation frames i have across all the cells. This then pretty much doubles every reload.

I've thrown this into the cell prepareForReuse:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    if imageView?.isAnimating() == true {
        NSLog("Stop Animating")
        imageView?.stopAnimating()
    }
    imageView?.animationImages = nil
    contentView.subviews.map({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
    imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: imageRect!)
    type = nil
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    contentView.addSubview(imageView!)
}
```

But to no avail. This isn't even getting called on reload. So, new cells are being created, but the old ones aren't being cleared properly maybe?

I've tried running this:

```
    func clearCellImages(){
    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells(){
        cell.imageView!?.animationImages = nil
        cell.imageView!!.image = nil
    }
}
```

On viewDidDisappear and deinit, but no difference.

It took me soooooo long to find this issue, and now that i have, I'm stumped. Happy to post any code you think will help, very happy to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: just release your resources once they finish. For example imageView.image = nil

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but when am i meant to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this turned out to be a two pronged solution. First i made these little helper functions:

```
func clearCells(){
    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells(){
        clearCell(cell as! MyCellView)
    }
}

func clearCell(cell:MyCellView){
    if let iv = cell.imageView {
        iv.animationImages = nil
        iv.image = nil
        iv.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

I called `clearCells` on `viewWillDisappear`, and saw a drop in the `UIImages` and memory use, however, if i had scrolled, which is more than likely, then the images that had been used in cells that were not currently visible were not de-referenced, resulting in a small, but not insignificant memory creep. I fixed this by calling `clearCell` on the `didEndDisplayingCell` delegate method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    clearCell(cell as! MyCellView)
}
```

I really would have thought that this kind of management could be handled, if not automatically by ARC, or by the `UICollectionView`, then at least manually through `prepareCellForReuse`, but apparently not.

Hope this helps someone :)